# MVVM sharing code Win8 and WP8 and file access

Tags: c#, mvvm, windows-phone-8, windows-store-apps, mvvm-light

I am working on small project, where I would like to learn about code sharing methods.
This solution include both Win8 and WP8 projects.

I need to load data from XML files which are stored in the memory of specific device.
(*Package.Current.InstalledLocation.Path* - Win8 and *IsolatedStorage* - WP8) and I am working with PCL for sharing code on assembly level.

I also would like to use repository pattern for [getting data from XML files](https://github.com/tkowalczyk/NumbersGame/tree/master/NumbersGame/NumbersGame.Shared/Services)
but in case of every system(Win8 and WP8) has different file access method I also plan to use something like [IFileStorage](https://github.com/tkowalczyk/NumbersGame/blob/master/NumbersGame/NumbersGame.Shared/Model/IFileStorage.cs) but I do not know how to connect these two in a good way to be able to use specific IFileStorage in the concrete project in ViewModel.
I am using MVVM Light Toolkit and [here is](https://github.com/tkowalczyk/NumbersGame) a GitHub repo of this solution.

Answer (score 2):

I would consider using the MvvmCross plugins. These do exactly as you mention and have an interface which your shared Portable Class Library works with, then has platform specific versions which can be place into an IOC container.

MvvmCross Plugins are here:
https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/tree/v3/Plugins/Cirrious

MvvmCross is here:
https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross

Comment: Thanks it is great tool but in this project I started with Mvvm Light and going to end with it.

Comment: You dont have to use the whole framework. You can just take the plugins. Thats the great thing about them.

Comment: Oo did not know it, but how to use only plugins? I can see them via NuGet (File plugin it is what I need) I should install it in every platformo or in PCL project?

Comment: you install it in the PCL, this gives you an interface to work with once resolved from your IOC container. You the add the nuget package to your WP8 and WinStore projects (it installs the correct version for you) and insert the platform specific version into your IOC container. Very easy to work with.

Comment: Ok so now I have [https://github.com/tkowalczyk/NumbersGame/blob/master/NumbersGame/NumbersGame.Shared/ViewModel/ViewModelLocator.cs#L32](ViewModelLocator) and in [https://github.com/tkowalczyk/NumbersGame/blob/master/NumbersGame/NumbersGame.Shared/Services/XmlService.cs](XmlService) I simply call `var fileService = Mvx.Resolve<IMvxFileStore>();` it is ok?

Comment: Thats the idea, i am getting a 404 on the links so cannot check but it sounds like you are on the right track.

Answer (score 1):

You mention you are using Mvvm Light. Oren Novotney has a portable Mvvm Library that you can use inside of a portable class library. Check it out [here](http://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/SourceControl/network/forks/onovotny/MvvmLightPortable).

Your next step will be to design controller interfaces that your platform-specific instances will implement. Then, all you have to do is register your platform-specific controller at app init. The portable libraries will be able to access them directly and you can have platform specific implementations.

Comment: Yes I am using Portable version of MVVM Light. What am I asking is how  to design this controller interface?

Comment: Okay, first and foremost you need to find out the operations you want to have. Generally they are Read/Write and maybe something like CheckIfFileExists. Now, make an interface that has a method signature for each of these. Make them return Task<ResultingType>. Then, when you create your implementation, you just make them `async Task<ResultingType>`. In your ViewModelLocator, make a property for your IController (whatever it's named) like you would any other VM, then at the start of your app, register your platform-specific controller. Then your PCL will be able to use it freely.

Comment: please have a look I did what you say but I still don't know how to register [platform-specific controller](https://github.com/tkowalczyk/NumbersGame/blob/master/NumbersGame/NumbersGame.Shared/ViewModel/ViewModelLocator.cs#L21) https://github.com/tkowalczyk/NumbersGame

Answer (score 0):

You can use `WinRT API` to access files in WP8 and Win8:

```
public class LocalFileStorage: IRepository<byte[]> 
    {
        private readonly string _fileName;

        public LocalFileStorage(string fileName)
        {
            _fileName = fileName;
        }

        public async Task<byte[]> LoadAsync()
        {
            try
            {
                var file = await GetFileAsync();
                using (var stream = await file.OpenStreamForReadAsync())
                {
                    var buffer = new byte[stream.Length];
                    await stream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                    return buffer;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                throw new RepositoryException("Unable load data from repository", e);
            }
        }

        public async Task SaveAsync(byte[] buffer)
        {
            try
            {
                var file = await GetFileAsync();
                using (var stream = await file.OpenStreamForWriteAsync())
                {
                    await stream.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                throw new RepositoryException("Unable save data to repository", e);
            }
        }

        private async Task<StorageFile> GetFileAsync()
        {
            StorageFile file = null;
            var notFound = false;

            try
            {
                file = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFileAsync(_fileName);
            }
            catch (FileNotFoundException)
            {
                notFound = true;
            }

            if (notFound)
            {
                file = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync(_fileName);
            }

            return file;
        }
    }
```

I use a `Factory` to create a repository for a `ViewModel`:

```
 public class FileStorageFactory: IRepositoryFactory
    {
        private const string SOME_FILE_NAME_1 = "FileName1.xml";
        private const string SOME_FILE_NAME_2= "FileName2.xml";

        public IRepository<byte[]> CreateFor1()
        {
            return new LocalFileStorage(SOME_FILE_NAME_1 );
        }

        public IRepository<byte[]> CreateFor2()
        {
            return new LocalFileStorage(SOME_FILE_NAME_2);
        }
    }
```

Comment: but what about using IoC container in [ViewModelLocator](https://github.com/tkowalczyk/NumbersGame/blob/master/NumbersGame/NumbersGame.Shared/ViewModel/ViewModelLocator.cs#L32) maybe better way is to write `XmlService : IQuestionService` for each platform?

Comment: I use factory to create a repository for a ViewModel. So a ViewModel uses IRepositoryFactory, check the answer, I have put a piece of code there.